# Angular 4 : How do I delete the row that is dynamically generated?

Tags: angular

I am building an Angular 4 Application in which I have details of a user. 
The table has an add button on click of which a row is dynamically generated. The row has few details of the user and a delete button to delete the corresponding row. I am able to create the rows dynamically. For deleting the corresponding row, I am not sure of doing it. I tried to assign a function like,

```
  <td> <input type="button" value="Delete" name="Delete" id="deleteRowBtn" (click)="deleteRow($(this))"></td>
```

deleteRow function has

```
console.log("deleting row");
   thisObj.closest('tr').empty();
```

This doesn't work. Can someone suggest on this please?

Comment: are u generating table rows using `*ngFor` ? please post code for the same

Comment: get the index of the row and use`array.splice(index, 1);`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to update your model from your component to delete the row.

```
<tr *ngFor=" let x of users; let i = index;">
   <td>{{x.someUserData}}</td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Delete" name="Delete" id="deleteRowBtn" (click)="deleteRow(i)"></td>
</tr>
```

Then you can splice from your collection using this index

```
deleteRow (index:number) {
   this.users.splice(index, 1); //replace your Model here instead of this.user
}
```